# Drawing a simple circle using Crafty.js and Box2d

Tags: javascript, jquery, box2d, craftyjs

i am trying to draw a simple circle using box2d with crafty.js but i can't seem to able to draw it 
this is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/B5UsC/2/

look at this part of the code :

```
var ball = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas,Color, Box2D,ball")
                .attr({ x: 10, y: 15, z:5 })
                .color("#fff")
            .box2d({
                bodyType: 'dynamic',
                density: 1.0,
                friction: 2,
                restitution: 0.2,
                shape: 'circle'
            }).onContact("Floor",
                        function (data) { 
                        alert("Hi");
                        });
```

the weird thing about it is that `alert` is executed but the ball is not showing . am i missing something please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The external resources

**Box2dWeb-2.1.a.3.js**

**box2d.js**

**crafty.js**

this directs to an [Unavailable Page](http://error404.000webhost.com/?) that's why it doesn't work in the fiddle

---

Try downloading the source [CraftyJS](http://craftyjs.com/download/),[Box2dweb](https://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/) and [Box2d](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/)

Try and see if that works for you.

Ok I got your code working, it seems that the reference library crafty+box2d is a mod made by the user who made the pong game.

You forgot to put the width `w` and height `h` attribute in the .attr of the ball object.

```
        var ball = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas,Color, Box2D,Ball")
            .attr({ x: 10, y: 15, z:5 , w:25,h:25 })
            .color("#dddddd")
        .box2d({
            bodyType: 'dynamic',
            density: 1.0,
            friction: 2,
            restitution: 0.2,
            shape: 'circle'
        }).onContact("Floor",
                    function (data) { 
                    alert("Hi");
                    });
```

On the other hand if you want the box outline eating the circle
remove the text `,color` in the string argument of `Crafty.e` and erase the .color property

```
        var ball = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas,ball, Box2D,")
            .attr({ x: 10, y: 15, z:5 , w:25,h:25 })

        .box2d({
            bodyType: 'dynamic',
            density: 1.0,
            friction: 2,
            restitution: 0.2,
            shape: 'circle'
        }).onContact("Floor",
                    function (data) { 
                    alert("Hi");
                    });
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: HTTP ERROR: 403

Problem accessing /file/seekpunk1-OrionContent/crafty/box2d.js. Reason:

    You are not authorized to access /file/seekpunk1-OrionContent/crafty/box2d.js

not a good site for uploading public external resources.

Comment: I checked your code and method of `Crafty` `Crafty.box2D.init` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't seem to exist i get the code from here : `https://github.com/shogoki-vnz/CraftyBox2D/blob/master/pong.js`

`ball = Crafty.e("2D, Canvas, ball, Box2D")
   .attr({ x: hw-15, y: 575, z: 1, isBall:true})
   .box2d({
     bodyType: 'dynamic',
     density : 1,
     friction : 0.2,
     restitution : 1,
     shape : 'circle'
    })`

Comment: I edited my answer please recheck :)

Ok I got your code working, it seems that the reference library crafty+box2d is a mod made by the user who made the pong game.

You forgot to put the width w and height h attribute in the .attr of the ball obje

Comment: adding a width and height will make the object a rectangle and not a ball :/ i wanted my object to be a ball

Comment: Please double check my answer this is not a rectangle. width and height only defines the size of the ball.

Using the string color in the attribute only displays a rectangle.

Please double check mine's only a ball falling, no rectangles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57981/discussion-between-sora-and-mike-ante).

Comment: can you please tell me how can i add a color to my circle when i am not using : `Crafty.box2D.showDebugInfo();`